# Meta Marketing API for "More Profile Visits" Objective - IG Boosted Post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api

We're trying to find API documentation to tie into the Boosted Post feature on Instagram for "More Profile Visits". All documentation I've found so far creates a traditional ad for link clicks, website visits, etc. and the Meta Documentation says to not use your Instagram Profile URL as the CTA link due to API error. Can anyone please advise how to tie into this ad objective?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/ads-api/guides/use-posts-as-ads/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/ads-api/guides/call-to-action/